# Передача в представление

Tags: asp.net, mvc

У меня есть задача сделать программу на ASP.NET MVC C#:
"У нас есть фирма, на фирме есть сотрудники. Каждый сотрудник делится на 2 типа(дизайнер и программист). Так же у них есть свой скил: (если дизайнер, то: фотошоп, графика ..., программист: PHP, Java, C, C++ ...). Если мы создали дизайнера, то не сможем ему уже добавить скил программиста и наоборот. Мы в роле админа"
Я создал класс сотрудников.

```
    public class Employee
        {
            public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string EmployeeType { get; set; }
        }
```

Так же класс со скилами.

```
public class Skill
        {
            public int SkillID { get; set; }
            public string SkillName { get; set; }
            public string SkillType { get; set; }
        }
```

И общий класс.

```
public class EmployeeSkill
        {
            public int EmployeeSkillID { get; set; }
            public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
            public int SkillID { get; set; }
        }
```

Entity framework.

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmployeeSkill> SkillOfEmployee { get; set; }
    }
```

Создал общую модель для всего этого.

```
public class EmployeesListViewModel
    {
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<EmployeeSkill> EmployeeSkills { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот контроллер.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private EFDbContext db = new EFDbContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Employees);
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            EmployeesListViewModel model = new EmployeesListViewModel();
            try
            {               
                model.Employee = db.Employees.Find(id);  //тут проблема 
                model.EmployeeSkills = db.SkillOfEmployee.Where(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
                model.Skills = db.Skills.Where(m => m.SkillType == db.Employees.Find(id).EmployeeType);          
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               // ViewBag.Message = e.Message;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(model);

        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(employee);
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
            db.Employees.Remove(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

Помогите правильно оформить вюшку и решить проблему на етапе, когда я ищу в базе 
юзера мне выдает ошибку, что "invalid cast" почему (в контроллере метод Details)?

Comment: А на `Index` у вас ничего не падает? Может просто у вас с `Details` на `Index` редиректит и он, собственно, и падает? Попробуйте швырнуть 
во вьюху `db.Employees.ToList()`

Comment: Не удается вызвать метод "DXWebApplication1.Models.Employee Find(System.Object[])", объявленный для типа "System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[DXWebApplication1.Models.Employee]", с экземпляром типа "System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[DXWebApplication1.Models.Employee]"

Comment: Не помогло с ToList();

Comment: Может проблема, что Find() ищет массив, а я его передаю  в одну  модель?

Comment: По идее тут все верно https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Да нет,  и Find() ищет одну, хах) проблемка

Comment: `Find()` возвращает один объект, вы его и сетаете в `EmployeesListViewModel.Employee`. Вроде все должно работать

Comment: Я провел id(которое идет на вход) - совпадает с номером в таблице.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `Find(id)` поставить `First(e => e.EmployeeID  == id)`;

Comment: Я так понял, что First(e => e.EmployeeID == id); использует метод Find()
и такой же ексепшн.